# How to compare equality of 2 boost::icl::interval_set

Tags: c++, boost

I wanted to know if there is a faster way to know if 2 boost::icl::interval_set are equal?

I tried the following conditions for faster results but I guess they are not complete:
1.comparing their size()
2.comparing the lowest element
3.Comparing the largest element

Brute force approach is to compare both of them element wise but if there is a known better way of comparison or some in-built function,please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the somewhat oddly named built-in function [**`is_element_equal`**](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/icl/doc/html/boost_icl/concepts/sets_and_maps.html) to compare equality of two 2 `boost::icl::interval_set`s.

Note that as per the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/icl/doc/html/boost_icl/concepts/sets_and_maps.html),

> Equality on Sets is not implemented as operator `==`, because operator `==` is used for the stronger lexicographical equality on segments, that takes the segmentation of elements into account.
>
> ```
> split_interval_set<time> w1, w2; //Pseudocode
> w1 = {[Mon       ..       Sun)}; //split_interval_set containing a week
> w2 = {[Mon .. Fri)[Sat .. Sun)}; //Same week split in work and week end parts.
> w1 == w2;                        //false: Different segmentation
> is_element_equal(w1,w2);         //true:  Same elements contained
> ```